# Chequear si un registro existe, si no insertar uno nuevo (PHP PDO POO MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, poo, pdo

Estoy intentando llamar las dos funciones que estan en productClass.php donde el formulario hace el request, cuando no existe me lo ingresa pero no logro que me muestre el mensaje cuando si existe.

insert.php (donde se dirige el formulario)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    require_once('productClass.php');
    $product = new Product();
    $prod = new Product();

    $product->setSku($_POST['sku']);
    $prod->setSku($_POST['sku']);
    $product->setName($_POST['name']);
    $product->setPrice($_POST['price']);
    $product->setSize($_POST['size']);
    $product->setWeight($_POST['weight']);
    $product->setWidth($_POST['width']);
    $product->setHeight($_POST['height']);
    $product->setLength($_POST['length']);

    if ($prod->askDatabase() == 1)
    { 
        echo "This SKU already exist"; 
    }
    else
    {
        $product->insertProduct();
        header("location:../index.php");
        
    }

}
?>
```

productClass.php

```
public function askDatabase()
    {
        try 
        {
            $stm = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM product WHERE sku = :sku");
            $stm->bindParam(":sku" , $this->sku);
            $stm->execute();
            return $result = $stm->fetch();
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Cualquier ayudita me sirve. Gracias

Comment: Qué obtienes en esta línea `$result = $stm->fetch();`? Puedes revisarlo usando la función `print_r($result);`.

Comment: No me muestra nada, puede ser que no estoy pasando bien el dato que se inserta a la consulta de la base de datos en insert.php? @DjCrazy

Comment: Es posible... Debes depurar tu código para ver hasta donde te llegan los datos.